# How to encode(shorten) the numeric str

Tags: java, encoding, base64

Imagine there is one numeric str:

Followings are the list of id, I need to merge them together to str and store it into DB, and when I need to use it, I need to translate it into the raw ids.
So I need to shorten the ids size....

`7376,89962,18299,74081,4094197,74445,807343,309251102,594649‌​555`

I use base64 encode the str to：
`NzM3Njg5OTE2MjE4Mjk5MTc0MDgxNDAxOTQxOTc3MTQ0NDU4MDcxMzQzMzA5MjE1MTEwMjU5MTQ2NDk1NTU=`

But it is too long actually.
Is there any ways I can shorten(encode) the str's length and decode it to the before?

Comment: How long is too long?

Comment: You would write your own methods for Encoding and Decoding where you can split your numeric string into length 6 (or whatever you want to divide it) and replace that string into lets say A. So, For e.g, 737689 into A, 962182 into B and so on. There are another ways to use different logics. I hope one of mine would help you.

Comment: Also, how are you encoding it? If you encode it as a string, it's going to be longer than if you treat it as a number.

Comment: Try this: `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(new BigInteger("7376899621829974081409419774445807343309251102594649555").toByteArray())`

Comment: Will changing the number string to a higher base will work?

Comment: Yes: don't encode it. There is zero need to encode it - base64 also contains the numbers in its set of characters it uses so if you cannot send numbers of your transport than you can't use base64 either

Comment: Erwin. is there any way to shorten them?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Huffman Coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) to compress data.

[Here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/55compression/Huffman.java.html) is the java example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String numText= "7376899621829974081409419774445807343309251102594649555";
        BigInteger bi= new BigInteger(numText);
        String encodedText= bi.toString(36);
        BigInteger nbi= new BigInteger(encodedText, 36);
        String originalText= nbi.toString();
```

The number string is shortened but by keeping intact the value.

Comment: Could u tell me why BigInteger make it shorter? Thanks!

Comment: It changed the base of the number from 10 to 36 thus decreasing the required number of characters by 19-20.

Comment: 7376,89962,18299,74081,4094197,74445,807343,309251102,594649555

Comment: There was no comma present previously

Comment: Ashish, I am sorry not to make clear...                do u have any ideal for the str(number) conatining char?

Comment: It's cool Wade. Just tell me your input and required output. If possible share more information.